# Why is my launchctl program not accepting external connections?

Tags: macos, launchd

I am trying to set up the [Check_MK](http://mathias-kettner.com/check_mk.html) agent with launchd on a Mac server, to return data over port 6556 when another machine connects to it.

(The agent itself is essentially just a shell script that outputs various information about the machine's status in a vaguely machine-readable format.)

I am able to connect to it from the machine itself, e.g. with `curl localhost:6556`, but if I try to connect externally, it just times out.

I have a .plist file set up like the one at [de.mathias-kettner.check_mk.plist](https://github.com/onecooltaco/check_mk-plugins/blob/master/osx/de.mathias-kettner.check_mk.plist), stored in /Library/LaunchDaemon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
        <dict>
                <key>HOME</key>
                <string>/var/root</string>
                <key>PATH</key>
                <string>/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>de.mathias-kettner.check_mk</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/local/bin/check_mk_agent</string>
        </array>
        <key>Sockets</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Listeners</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>SockServiceName</key>
                        <string>6556</string>
                </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Wait</key>
                <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/check_mk.err</string>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/var/root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(The only difference is that the check_mk_agent is /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin, because I couldn't create the file there.)

The check_mk_agent file itself can be found at: [check_mk_agent.macosx](http://git.mathias-kettner.de/git/?p=check_mk.git;a=blob;f=agents/check_mk_agent.macosx)

The strange thing is, if I point the .plist file to something like `/bin/date`, then it works externally as well.

The only thing I can conclude is that the task runs with different permissions depending on the IP or interface the connection comes from, but I don't know how to change the permissions it tries to run with.

Comment: I have no problem to curl a remote machine and getting all details with [check_mk_agent](https://github.com/onecooltaco/check_mk-plugins/blob/master/osx/check_mk_agent) running there. The plist is root:wheel. The file *check_mk_agent* is also root:wheel **and** chmod +x. Check **your** error file at */var/log/check_mk.err*! Additional: did you modify `export MK_LIBDIR` and `export MK_CONFDIR` in *check_mk_agent.macosx* and did you create the appropriate files & folders in the system?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the suggestions.  I have created the necessary folders, and checked the permissions.  The error file is empty.  But it still continues to only allow localhost connections.

Answer (score 1):

why you are not using ssh to request the data from the agent at the mac?
https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_datasource_programs.html
You need not the launchd.

regards,
Oliver

Comment: Thanks, this is potentially good advice.  I wasn't the person to originally set it up, but I may consider switching to this method.  I am still intrigued by the original problem though.

Comment: Note: at time of writing the above URL seems to have vanished, but http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_datasource_programs.html seems to work.  Perhaps they are migrating to a new server.